# How to handle interactive commands in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line

I have a perl script which calls a command which before executing asks for confirmation. How do I handle this in Perl?

For  example let say in my perl script I am doing the following

```
`ssh myServer`;
```

Before connecting I get a prompt asking to proceed or not. I have to provide yes as my next command. How can I achieve this? Any code snippet would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at interactive  you can use [Expect](https://metacpan.org/source/RGIERSIG/Expect-1.21) on the CPAN...

```
"Expect is a generic tool for talking to processes that normally require
user interaction. This might be running an ftp client to grab a file,
telnetting to a router to grab statistics or reset an interface. Or, as in the
case of a place I recently administered, to start up a secure webserver without
having to be physically at the machine to enter the super secret password."
```

However, there are other (better) methods to automate SSH login. I.e. by using [ssh-keygen](http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html)

Comment: This is the best method IMO if you control both hosts.

Answer (score 0):

From  [Net::SSH](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-1.35/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) :

**interactive** 
Set to a true value if you're using Net::SSH::Perl interactively. This is used in determining whether or not to display password prompts, for example. It's basically the inverse of the BatchMode parameter in ssh configuration.

Defaults to false.